# Buliding a larger matrix from a smaller one

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning

I have my matrix $h$ of size $2N\times 2N$ in this form

$$h=\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $a,b,c,d$ are smaller matrices which i don't know.
Is there any simple way to get this matrix?
$$\begin{pmatrix}
a &0& b&0 \\
0 &a& 0&b\\
c &0& d&0 \\
0 &c& 0&d\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: Check out `KroneckerProduct`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
MatrixForm[h = {{a, b}, {c, d}}]
```

> $ h=\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  a & b \\
>  c & d \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

```
KroneckerProduct[h, IdentityMatrix@2] // MatrixForm
```

> $ \left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  a & 0 & b & 0 \\
>  0 & a & 0 & b \\
>  c & 0 & d & 0 \\
>  0 & c & 0 & d \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Comment: thank you,it is exactly what i wanted!